How should I attach a short deck railing against the house wall?
The deck came with the house and its railing is moving when I push against it. I thought the area near the siding must have 4x4.

Q: How do I secure the railing?
Option 1: Should I just bolt the railing to a 2x4 sitting flat against the siding? This sounds wrong with all the moisture and gaps.
Option 2: Add a new 4x4 and secure it with 4 bolts on the bottom near the siding but not attach to siding.

What's going on with the top rail? It should be continuous through that area, which would eliminate the problem of the short section moving. Why is it incomplete?

@isherwood It was under replacement so the bad top rail was removed when I took pics.

How much is it moving when you're providing good pressure against it?  You want it strong enough to support a body bumping into it with good force without significant give, whether it's anchored to your house or not.  If you could include pictures of how those 4x4s are attached to the deck structure underneath, that would help provide some guidance on how to make them firm.

I see a portion of the rail cap there. The rest of it seems to be missing. If you were to fasten that properly your issue would go away. It'll be stiff enough horizontally to anchor the short rail below it.
I would get more of the same board (possibly 5/4 decking boards or 1x6) and complete the top cap so you have a proper rest for elbows and drinks. Locate all splices where they'll create the least reduction in rigidity where it's needed.
